# How to call a function of postgis-1.5.dll in c code

Tags: postgresql, dll, postgis, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.0

I'm creating an Postgresql extension in c that use Postgis Point.  when i try to call a function of postgis-1.5.dll after loading it, it fails and i get no error message
Here is a small part of my code:

```
    Point *pt =(Point*) palloc(sizeof(Point));
    bool test;
    HINSTANCE DLLHandle;
typedef bool(*ST_empty)(Point*);

ST_emptyPtr ST_empty;

    pt->x = 0.2;
    pt->y = 0.9;
DLLHandle = LoadLibrary(L"postgis-1.5.dll");
ST_empty = (ST_emptyPtr)GetProcAddress(DLLHandle,"LWGEOM_isempty"); 
if (DLLHandle != NULL){
   if(!ST_empty)
     elog(ERROR,"null ehhhh");

   test = ST_empty(p);
       elog(ERROR,"not empty");
    }
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It may help to look at the source:
[lwgeom_is_empty from PostGIS Trunk](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/postgis-doxygen/d3/dc8/lwgeom_8c-source.html#l01105)

Are you sure it's failing? The code above doesn't test the return value from the function call. What does the following do?

```
if (!ST_empty(p))
  elog(ERROR,"not empty");
```

Brian